# Java interfaces in annotation value

Tags: java, enums, annotations

Why does the java compiler not allow using interfaces in annotations?

I can use enums in an annotation:

```
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
    SomeEnum[] value() default {};
}
```

I can implement an interface in an enum:

```
public enum SomeEnum implements SomeInterface {
   NAME1, NAME2; 
}
```

but I can't use interfaces in annotations:

```
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
    SomeInterface[] value() default {};
}
```

Quite frustrating...

Answer (score 3):

Because an interface is not a valid return type, as per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6) the return type of a method declared in an annotation type must be one of the following, or a compile-time error occurs:

> A primitive type
>
> String
>
> Class or an invocation of Class (§4.5)
>
> An enum type
>
> An annotation type
>
> An array type whose component type is one of the preceding types
>   (§10.1).